# Change the height of children columns in Antd Table

Tags: css, reactjs, excel, antd

I need to copy table structure from excel file and draw it in antd table.

For table like this:

[image: table from excel]

I get columns object like this:

```json
[
    {
        "title": "Item",
        "children": [
            {"title": 1}
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Index",
        "children": [
            {"title": 2}
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Params",
        "children": [
            {
                "title": "Value",
                "children": [
                    {"title": 3}
                ]
            },
            {
                "title": "Style",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "title": "Color",
                        "children": [
                            {"title": 4}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Font",
                        "children": [
                            {"title": 5}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Problem start when i render Atnd Table, it sets row height by itself
(i want the height of "Item" and "Index" cells to be 3 rows (like in excel), "1", "2", "3" cell`s height to be 1 rows etc, basically, just like in excel file.
[image]

From a parsed file i can get every column height in cells.
But how can i ajust height in antd table?